# fetching results twice returns nil

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Assume I have 3 files in my project:

1. data model file, dealing with Core Data and fetching info
2. viewController 1
3. viewController 2

In the model file I get results us follows:

```
- (NSArray *) getColonyData
{
NSManagedObjectContext *cxt = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *colonyDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Colony" inManagedObjectContext:cxt];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:colonyDesc];

NSError *error;
NSArray *colonyResults = [cxt executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

return colonyResults;
}
```

I run this part of code in viewDidLoad section of the 1st viewController and I get proper results:

```
  NSArray *colonyResults = [model getColonyData];
    if (colonyResults != nil)
    {
        colonyName.text = [[colonyResults objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"name"];
    }
    else
    {
        colonyName.text = @"nothing setup yet";
    }
```

Then I move via a segue to a 2nd viewController, when I execute exactly same code (of course updating different UI elements). **But this time the result is nil**. What am I doing wrong here? Should I release results manually first? No other errors appear.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the value of `model` something valid in your second controller?

Comment: In both controllers the header of the model file is imported: `#import "experimentModel.h"` and it's assigned in both controllers as follows: `experimentModel *model;`. Then getColonyData is accessible in both...

Comment: Actually... I found out that the call for `getColonyData` in the 2nd controller is not even executed. The debugger just goes over it. It could explain why results are empty. Still... Why does it do it?

Comment: `experimentModel *model;` doesn't assign anything; it just declares that a variable exists.  Somewhere, you must be setting `model` to an actual object for the first controller (and probably not doing that for the second one).  As I said, look at the value of `model` in each case where you attempt to get the results.

Comment: @PhillipMills yes... silly me. `model = [[experimentModel alloc] init];` how come i missed that... time to have a break. thanks Philip! If you want to answer it in the thread, i'll mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments:

`experimentModel *model;` doesn't assign anything; it just declares that a variable exists. Somewhere, you must be setting model to an actual object for the first controller (and probably not doing that for the second one).

Sending messages to nil objects is a common way to **not** get the results one was expecting.  :)